# Excel Copy / Paste Specific Discrete Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, copy-paste

There are a lot of questions pertaining to copy / paste on excel but I do not think there is one that is describing this exact situation that I am finding myself in.

I am on Excel 2011 Mac and when I try to select a few discrete cells out of many it is grabbing the values in between these cells on my clipboard.  Ex. Say I want to grab contents from B1, B4, B7.  If I cntrl click these specific cells and then hit copy it will copy B1-B7.  What gives?  And how do I get just the contents of B1, B4, B7?  Thanks all.

Comment: When you select them, do they highlight individually as expected? Once copied, do you get the blinking border around the individual cells as expected? Did you try hiding or filtering out the rows you don't want to copy? Try that and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, they highlight as expected - only around the squares I want - as soon as I hit copy though and paste, say to a microsoft word doc, I magically have all the contents in between the cells in addition to the cells I selected.  How do I create a filter to hide specific cells?  Would it have to be a super advanced one that specifically targets an attribute about that cell?

Comment: Try holding the command button instead of Ctrl

Comment: When I saying cntrl I was actually hitting command - my bad.  However, I did find something interesting.  When I paste in Excel, it pastes only the values I have actively clicked.  But not altering what is on the clipboard whatsoever, when I paste again in a text editor - I have all the values in between included.  Argh so frustrating.

Comment: Gotcha. I didn't realize you were looking to paste them into another program. I guess you'll have to copy the individual cells, paste them somewhere in the same workbook (so that you get the values you want in adjacent cells), copy them again, then paste into the text editor.

Comment: Good point - that will work.  Sooo how do I give you credit for this answer given that it is comment form?  Wanna type up your answer beneath this and I'll upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you'll have to copy the individual cells, paste them somewhere in the same workbook (so that you get the values you want in adjacent cells), copy them again, then paste into the text editor.